# Blender 2.8 - Pro Lighting Sky and Studio -

Tags: cycles-render-engine

how do I install Pro Lighting Sky and Studio in Blender 2.8?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! The way you asked your question as of now it is rather a tutorial request than normal question and thus likely considered to be [off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6), as it also suggests that you have done little research yourself. Can you please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/148249/edit) your question and add what you have already tried and where it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check on the blendermarket website for version 1.2.4 and download it then just go into user preferences in blender install from file and locate the .zip file. restart pc and it should be there .If you have migrated your settings from 2.79 to 2.8. if you haven't yet then you need to download and install the hdri's to.

Comment: You don't have to restart the whole computer after installing an addon, you shouldn't even have to restart Blender most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you've already downloaded all the zip files. There's no need to unpack any of them.

Go to *Edit* > *Preferences.* Then click the *Add-ons* tab and press *Install.* From the file explorer that pops up, find and select the *pro_lighting_skies_ultimate_v_1.2.4.zip* file.

Next, check the box next to the *Node: Pro Lighting: Skies* add-on.

[image]

To finish installing, follow the steps shown. Note: directly after you select the HDR zip files (you'll have to do them one by one), **DO NOT MOVE THE MOUSE.** A small pop-up window shows up asking you to confirm and that Blender will freeze for a while during the install. If you move the mouse out of that box, it'll disappear and you'll have to reselect the file.

The Pro Lighting Studio can be installed the same way except you don't have to do the HDR zip part.